# Add all the frequencies of array elements into one array, and its elements to another array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, kotlin

n=8  -> number of elements
1 3 2 4 2 1 9 1  -> Elements of an array

Output:

numbers = [1, 3, 2, 4, 9]
frequency = [3, 1, 2, 1, 1]

```
var n = 8
var a = arrayOf(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 9, 1)
var numbers = Array(50){}
var frequency = Array(50){}

var k = 0



for (i in 0 until a.size){
    for(j in 1 until a.size){
        if (a[j]!=a[j+1]){
            k++
            println(k)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea of what to do? Pleas help me

Comment: You only have to go once over your array, you need a dictionary (Key,Value pair) to store how often you find a number and each time increment the value. E.g. First elemen is 1, not yet in dictionary so add it and increment the Value to one, next time you find one, only increment. At the end read out the dictionary..

Comment: As this is clearly for learning purposes, I won't provide you with a working solution (yet), but I have some suggestions. Don't do this in a single step. It is possible, but harder to do and it will produce less readable code. First create a histogram (use a map) and then transform this map into two separate arrays.

Comment: As a starting point, you might want to look at [hashmaps](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an array `a`.

```
var a = arrayOf(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 9, 1)
```

We will create two MutableList to store the numbers and their frequencies

```
var numbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
var frequencies = mutableListOf<Int>()
```

Now we will iterate over our array `a` and for an element `i`, if `i` is not in `numbers`, we will add `i` in `numbers` and add 1 in `frequencies`. And if `i` is already in `numbers`, we will find the index of `i` in `numbers` and use this index to update the frequency of `i` in `frequencies`, increasing by 1.

```
for(i in a){
    if(i !in numbers){
        numbers.add(i)
        frequencies.add(1)
    }
    else{
        var indexToChange = numbers.indexOf(i)
        frequencies[indexToChange] = frequencies[indexToChange]+1
    }
}
```

Now we will print the value of `numbers` and `frequencies`

```
println("numbers:     $numbers\nfrequencies: $frequencies")
```

Now adding all the pieces...

```
fun main(){
   var a = arrayOf(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 9, 1)
   var numbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
   var frequencies = mutableListOf<Int>()

   for(i in a){
          if(i !in numbers){
                 numbers.add(i)
                 frequencies.add(1)
          }
          else{
                 var indexToChange = numbers.indexOf(i)
                 frequencies[indexToChange] = frequencies[indexToChange]+1
          }
   }
   println("numbers:     $numbers\nfrequencies: $frequencies")
}
```

Results:

```
numbers:     [1, 3, 2, 4, 9]
frequencies: [3, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```